# I want to edit and save and new entered value in the Billing country is stored the appropriate account by using apex code

Tags: apex, visualforce, code

My Page:

```
<apex:page controller="UpdateBillingAddressController">
    <apex:form>
        <apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:pageBlockTable var="account" value="{!AccountList}" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="50%" >               
                <apex:column value="{!account.Id}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!account.Name}"/>
                <apex:column value="{!account.Phone}"/>               
                <apex:column value="{!account.BillingCountry}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockTable>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

My controller:

```
public class UpdateBillingAddressController{
 public List<Account> AccountList {
        get { 
        //To query the fields of the Id,Name,Phone,BillingCountry of the particular account followingly          
              AccountList = [SELECT Id, Name, Phone, BillingCountry FROM Account]; 
        return AccountList;
        }       
        set;
  } 
 }
```

So here I don't know the how to add the edit and save button to code and the check box also in the selecting purpose to which the account to be edited and saved to identify. So please help me to complete the task.For advance thanks for repliers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `WrapperClass` here to display checkbox and allow users to Edit and save.

Here is a sample code for you

## Controller Page:

```
public class wrapperclass
{
 wrapper objwrapper;
 List<wrapper> lstwrapper=new List<wrapper>();
  public integer rowIndex{get;set;}

  public wrapperclass(){
  lst = new list<wrapper>();
     List<Account> lstaccount=[select name,industry,type from account]; 

     for(integer i=0;i<lstaccount.size();i++)
     {
       objwrapper=new wrapper();
       objwrapper.act=lstaccount[i];
        objwrapper.isEdit = false;
       objwrapper.rowNo = lst.size();
       lst.add(objwrapper);
     }

  }
 public List<wrapper> lst{get;set;}
 public pagereference editmethid(){
     if(lst.size()>rowIndex){
         lst[rowIndex].isEdit = true;
     }
     return null;
 }

  public pagereference savemethid(){
     if(lst.size()>rowIndex){
         update lst[rowIndex].act;   
         lst[rowIndex].isEdit = false;
     }
     return null;
 }

 public class wrapper{
 public Account act{get;set;}
 public integer rowNo {get;set;}
 public boolean isEdit{get;set;}
 }
}
```

## Page Code:

```
<apex:page controller="wrapperclass">
  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock id="thePB">
  <apex:pageblocktable value="{!lst}" var="a">
  <apex:column headerValue="Action">
      <apex:commandlink value="Edit" rerender="thePB" rendered="{!NOT(a.isEdit)}" action="{!editmethid}">
          <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!a.rowNo}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}"/>
      </apex:commandLink>
      <apex:commandlink value="Save" rerender="thePB" rendered="{!a.isEdit}" action="{!savemethid}">
         <apex:param name="rowNumber" value="{!a.rowNo}" assignTo="{!rowIndex}"/>
      </apex:commandLink>         
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column HeaderValue="Name">
  <apex:outputField value="{!a.act.name}" rendered="{!NOT(a.isEdit)}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!a.act.name}" rendered="{!a.isEdit}"/>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column HeaderValue="Type">
  <apex:outputField value="{!a.act.type}" rendered="{!NOT(a.isEdit)}"/>
  <apex:inputField value="{!a.act.type}" rendered="{!a.isEdit}"/>
  </apex:column>
  <apex:column HeaderValue="Industry">
  <apex:outputField value="{!a.act.industry}" rendered="{!NOT(a.isEdit)}" />
  <apex:inputField value="{!a.act.industry}" rendered="{!a.isEdit}"/>
  </apex:column>
  </apex:pageblocktable>
  </apex:pageBlock>
  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: It's really helpful for some part but i try to provide the check box for selecting the accounts for edit and save in multiple manner in one time but as per your code done a great job.

Comment: @MohanRaj if you want it for multiple line then you need to display all fields in edit mode and user select many checkbox and then you need iterate the list in controller and get all selected records and update the list.